# Executing a script when DHCPD give an IP

Tags: linux, shell-script, dhcp-server, bind, nagios

i want to do a setting to dynamically monitor my Work Station on my Wifi network.
I've got my name server BIND and my dhcpd server all of that under linux working perfectly.
But i didn't find any option to execute a script when dhcp give an IP to a machine.
I would like to know if there is a way to do that.
If there is no options for that i'll use the log files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1328967

Here's the copy-paste from the above link:

```
on commit {
        set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
        set ClientMac = binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6));
        log(concat("Commit: IP: ", ClientIP, " Mac: ", ClientMac));
        execute("/usr/sbin/my_script_here", "commit", ClientIP, ClientMac);
}
```

It might be different for different versions of Linux, but should give you the idea.

See here for another example:

- https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2008-September/007167.html

`man dhcpd.conf` should also give you more information.

Baiscally, you want to use `on commit` and `execute` inside it to specify a script to be run.

Comment: It's the `on commit` examples in those links that you want. It's in the man page in the "Reference: events" section. icyrock.com, how about copy/paste one of those examples in your answer?

Comment: Perfect the key word commit was missing during my investigations.